# Importance of ADC Speed for Accelerator Pedal Position Sensor (APPS)

Tags: microcontroller, adc, potentiometer, electric-machine, fifo

We are building a electric vehicle and need an accelerator pedal position system.

We have the circuit designed as shown below.

When simulating our circuit, the ADC speed of the Arduino Uno seemed slow. We have looked into others.

We are trying to take values from the potentiometers to do a moving average to get smoother operation.

What would be a good sample rate for a pedal position system so we can take the moving averages of values from two different potentiometers (two seperate n vectors, first in first out,) compare the averages to each other (so they are within 10% error,) and to take the averages of the two vectors to send it to our driver?

Edit: I know we should be figuring this out ourselves, but we are not in a place to conduct experiments, plus we do not have the budget to try new microcontrollers. I asked this question to see how others managed their similar work based on the ADC sample rate. We are preparing for an event and we should have chosen a microcontroller to be bought by now. We do not have much time to try figuring things out, not to mention we have no experience in this sort of thing.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141204/discussion-on-question-by-kalamakra-importance-of-adc-speed-for-accelerator-peda).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding user interface, 30Hz sampling is definitely too slow for a mouse, 60Hz is absolutely fine... and the inertia of a mouse pointer is much lower than the inertia of your motor.

I'd go with an analog lowpass filter with a much lower cutoff than your motor PWM frequency to avoid noise, maybe something like a 100Hz second order filter. You already have the opamp, so that costs you a bunch of passives.

Then, 60Hz sampling, oversampled 10x, so 600Hz on the ADC. Out of every 10 samples, keep the median, that should be very resistant to noise.

Regarding cabling, you should use the pot as a pot, not as a variable resistor. Still, you should insert resistors in series with the pot at both ends, so the analog range goes from 0.5V to 4.5V. Then, a reading of 0V or 5V mean there is a problem with the wiring (short or wire came off).

If the two pots are for redundancy they should use separate cables, and cables should be shielded.

Note if the 5V line shorts to ground, this will short the power to the arduino. Perhaps a separate 5V LDO with current limit would be a good idea.